# JQuery Check All/ Uncheck All not working on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#chkRFI').click(
         function() {
             $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', $('#chkRFI').is(':checked'));
         });   }); 


<div class="grid_3">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="boxheader">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRFI" runat="server" Text="RFI" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="boxbody">
                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstRFI" runat="server" CssClass="boxbodylist">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="RFI No" Value="RFI" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="RFI Date" Value="RFI_Date" />
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

How to solve? Please provide me any ideas...
Thanks

Comment: for badge, u can go and check that link.... [Badges](http://stackoverflow.com/badges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that solution by ysrb should work - but you may also try alternate selectors - for example:

```
var checkAll = $('.boxheader input');
checkAll.click(function() { 
   $('.boxbody input').attr('checked', checkAll.attr('checked'));
});
```

Comment: yes bro... your one is really worked... and @ysrb 's one also should work cos wherever I search for solution... all solutions are like him... but I don't know why

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$('#<%= chkRFI.ClientID %>')` instead of `$('#chkRFI')`

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%= chkRFI.ClientID %>').click(
             function() {
                 $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', $('#<%= chkRFI.ClientID %>').is(':checked'));
             });
});     
so i changed like that, still cannot :(
but If I used like that, '#ctl00_Body_chkRFI' is okay... but u know it's so funny..

Comment: I think you changed from chkRFI to checkAll. Please change it to $('#<%= chkAll.ClientID %>') . Can you also update the whole code?

Comment: no bro... I didn't change. that's my asp code
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRFI" runat="server" Text="RFI" /> //Check All
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstRFI" runat="server" CssClass="boxbodylist"> // Check list
                                <asp:ListItem Text="RFI No" Value="RFI" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="RFI Date" Value="RFI_Date" />
                            </asp:CheckBoxList>

Comment: oh! my one's using windows authentication for intranet :( sorry for that bro

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET then all element IDs will be generated in very ugly form, e.g. $Form1$$MyCheckBox (in is not exactly the correct sample, but it shows the main idea). If you are using ASP.NET 4 you can disable this feature in web.config ([pages clientIDMode="static" /]). Analyze your checkbox with FireBug or simply view the page source to make sure that checkbox was generated with correct ID. Hope this helps...

Comment: oh! my one is 3.5 SP1, but ur information is really nice... thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Check/Uncheck All CheckBoxes Using JQuery</title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#chkAll').click(
             function() {
                 $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', $('#chkAll').is(':checked'));
             });
         });    

     </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" Text="Check All" /><br />

        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbList" runat="server">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[here is the complete example](http://www.iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/7/9/Check-All-Checkboxes-with-JQuery)

Comment: same with my one, right? but not working... I think cos of seperate div, is it true?